# How can Firestore check a collection to allow write (rules)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I use a collection called "admin" in Firestore to define which users can write new documents (image below).

At moment, it is controled just by software. I would like to add rules to Firestore. I tried the rule below but it didn't work. What would be the correct rules in that case ?

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if get(/admin/{anyDocument}).data.userId == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

[image: scheme]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far i know this is not possible with your current database structure. Because the push key is not accessible in firestore rules unless it is with in the `admin` node.

One way is to save the `admin` with their `uid` as key like `admin/userID/data...`

now you can access it

```
allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/admin/$(request.auth.uid)).data.userId == request.auth.uid;;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend instead having a `users` collection with an `admin` field that can be set to `true`/`false`. Then you can do something like:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if get(/users/${request.auth.uid}).data.admin == true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: where does `request.auth.uid` come from ?

Comment: If the client is authenticated via Firebase Auth, `request.auth` will be automatically populated when using the Firestore SDK.

Comment: what if i want to set the rules in a specific collection .how do i go about it